# Associating automated tests with test cases in azure devops using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, azure-devops

Please tell me if it's possible to associate Azure DevOps test cases with JUnit automated tests from eclipse. If yes, is there any step by step document I can follow? Please help

Answer (score 1):

As I know it's not supported scenario.

You can find the supported tests from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops#q-what-types-of-tests-are-supported):

- Coded UI test, Selenium tests, and unit tests written using Version 1 of the MSTest framework can be associated with a test case.
- Tests that use MSTest v2, NUnit, and xUnit frameworks can be associated with a test case workitem when using Visual Studio 15.9 Preview 2 or later. However, these tests cannot be run using Microsoft Test Manager and XAML builds.
- Tests that use the .NET core framework can be associated with a test case workitem when using Visual Studio 15.9 Preview 2 or later. To run the .NET core tests the appropriate target framework must be specified in a runsettings file. However, these tests cannot be run using Microsoft Test Manager and XAML builds.
- Tests that use other test frameworks such as Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests such as Mocha or QUnit), or Jest cannot be associated with a test case.
- Associating generic tests may work, but running these tests is not supported.

So we recommend using Visual Studio to associate the automated tests. And for now the Junit framework is not supported in such scenario.